# Grids and numeric values alignment

Tags: genexus

I am starting to develop web in GeneXus.
When using a simple grid, I noticed that genexus automatically aligns numeric values to the right (style being applied directly in the td tags, overriding my class customization).

How can I change this in order to show all values (and titles) aligned to the left?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jaime, for GeneXus X Evolution 3, you can create a new class in your theme, under `GridColumn`. Then, set `text-align: left !important;` in the "Custom CSS Properties" property, and set the newly created class as the `Column Class` of the numeric column you want to left align.

For GeneXus older versions, you can override the right alignment set by GeneXus in the values, but not the title. For this, you have to create a new class in your theme, under `Attribute`. Then, set `Float=Left` in the class properties, and set the newly created class as the control class (`Class` property) of the column you want to left align in your grid.